# get state true/false for a toggle switch in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the state of this switch for a chrome extension for learning the purpose, below is my sample code to just access the toggle switch `onchange` event and change the colour of some text.

Code is as follows:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var togBtn = document.getElementById('togBtn');
  togBtn.addEventListener('onchange', function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
  });
});
```

```html
<label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" value="false" name="disableYXLogo">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
```

How can I get the state of the toggle switch and perform my required task?

Comment: Always start by debugging the code, don't just guess. You can open devtools for your extension's popup by right-clicking the popup, then clicking "Inspect". There you can check the console panel for errors. And Source panel allows you to inspect the code, set breakpoints, inspect variables. You can find many tutorials that show how to use devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var togBtn = document.getElementById('togBtn');
  togBtn.addEventListener('change', function() {
    onChnage();
  });

  function onChnage() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = togBtn.checked ? "red" : "blue";
  }
  onChnage();
});
```

```html
<label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" value="false" name="disableYXLogo">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
          </label>
<div id='demo'>I am the text of demo.</div>
```